# How to have checkmarks icons (accessory view) on tableview already checked after cells rendered?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, accessorytype

I have model data, which has a boolean value that says if checkmark should be shown (accessoryType is .checkmark)...

So for example, I want to have two of five rows checkmarked at start (based on my model as I said)... The thing is, I am able to show checkmarks, but after I tap on them, toggling doesn't work right:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = true


    }
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = false


    }
}

And here is a cellForRowAt:

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let data = model[indexPath.row]
    let identifier = data.subtitle != nil ? kSubtitleID : kNormalID

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = data.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.subtitle

    return cell
}
```

I am able to show check mark like this:

```
cell.accessoryType = data.isCellSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

But when I tap on it, it cause it is selected (allowsMultipleSelection is set to true), it doesn't get toggled, but rather stays for the first time.

Here is the model I use. It is really simple:

```
struct CellModel{
    var title:String?
    var subtitle:String?
    var isCellSelected:Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Just show the model structure you using, it can be done by `cellForRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt`..

Comment: @vaibhav I added model example.

Comment: if you still stuck i delivered my ans just have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You should perform toggling in `tableView:didSelectRowAt:` only, and reload the necessary cell afterwards. You should omit `tableView:didDeselectRowAt:`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        // Toggle the value - true becomes false, false becomes true
        model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = !model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .none)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = model[indexPath.row]
    let identifier = data.subtitle != nil ? kSubtitleID : kNormalID

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = data.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.subtitle
    // Set the checkmark or none depending on your model value
    cell.inputAccessoryType = data.isCellSelected ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell
}
```

Edit:

Use this for single selection only + ability to deselect selected item:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Loop through all model items
    for (index, item) in model.enumerated() {
        if (index == indexPath.row) {
            // Toggle tapped item
            item.isCellSelected = !item.isCellSelected
        } else {
            // Deselect all other items
            item.isCellSelected = false
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData();
}
```

Comment: Hey, it worked, thanks! I remember I had problem with this approach once earlier, but can't really say if it was the same situation (likely not), but I still skipped it hah.

Comment: No problem. Make sure your `tableView:cellForRowAt:` method reflects any state your cell might be in synced to your model since if you modify a `UITableViewCell` object directly in `tableView:didSelectRowAt:` method only and scroll the cells off screen the'll be re rendered and all changes to them not reflected in the model will be lost. Might be a bit confusing, sorry.

Comment: The thing is, it works when allowsMultipleSelection = true, but it doesn't work for a tableview with a single selection...

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use select and deselect until you have a model that saves the boolean value
In tableview didselect method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if model[index.row].isCellSelected == true {
            model[indexpath.row].isCellSelected = false
        }
        else {
            model[indexpath.row].isCellSelected = true
        }
        tableview.reloadData

}
```

And in cell for row check

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if model[index.row].isCellSelected{
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make all work is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let data = model[indexPath.row]
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = true

            self.selectedData?(model.filter{$0.isCellSelected})
        }
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let data = model[indexPath.row]
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = false

            self.selectedData?(model.filter{$0.isCellSelected})
        }
    }
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let data = model[indexPath.row]
        let identifier = data.subtitle != nil ? kSubtitleID : kBasicID

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = data.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.subtitle

        cell.accessoryType = data.isCellSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
```

but I had to initially setup which cells are selected actually:

```
func setSelectedCells(){

        let selectedIndexes = self.model.enumerated().compactMap { (index, element) -> IndexPath? in
            if element.isCellSelected{
                return IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            }
            return nil
        }

        selectedIndexes.forEach{
            selectRow(at: $0, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
```

and then called this in viewDidAppear, cause I had to be sure that table has drawn its content (cause this will fail if we try something (cell) that doesn't exist yet). Not a best way, but it solved the issue for **single** and **multiple** selections with **initial states**.

Comment: it can be done in a fewer line of code or methods to show selected options at any state.

Answer (score 0):

Then, `cellForRowAt` method becomes as simple as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = model[indexPath.row]
    let identifier = data.subtitle != nil ? kSubtitleID : kNormalID

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = data.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.subtitle

    cell.accessoryType = data.isCellSelected ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell
}
```

Then, `didSelectRowAt` method becomes as simple as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {        
        let isCellSelected = !(model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected)
        cell.accessoryType = isCellSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = isCellSelected
    }
}
```

Note we had to toggle the flag and update the cell and the model based on the new value.

Even better, you can replace the .accessory type updating line with:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

So the method would look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {        
        let isCellSelected = !(model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected)
        model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = isCellSelected
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Note that we update the `model`, then we reload the cell that will cause `cellForRowAt` to be called, and that method takes care on proper configurations based on model.

More generally, I'd recommend to use some `StateController` object to keep the state for each cell / row and take care of the `toggling`.

I've wrote a whole article a while ago that does exactly what you need to do, and showcases a lot of best practices too:

https://idevtv.com/how-to-display-a-list-of-items-in-ios-using-table-views/

Comment: I will try this ... Have you tried it? Does this works for both single and multiple selections based tables  (with some cells already checked at start)? By the way I gave all code I have so you can reproduce issue by youself if you have time.

Comment: Yes, that's production code and it works. My code allows you to select many cells. My table has actually allowsMultipleSelection set ta false. On selection, it deselects the row with default animation, but it tracks that, sets / hides the checkmark as needed and set the true / false flag inside the array from the State Controller class.

Answer (score 0):

@Whirlwind, Hi its not so complicate if you need to show selections only inside the `tableView`, here i am delivering my ans after your model update.

**This can be done by maintaining `isCellSelected` property in `didSelectRowAt` only.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected ? false : true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Here is `cellForRowAt` you can also alter some more lines here.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = model[indexPath.row]
    let identifier = "kNormalID"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.subtitle
    cell.accessoryType = data.isCellSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

Hope i delivered you my best. Let me know if i missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try following!

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        model[indexPath.row].isCellSelected = false
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: <UITableViewRowAnimation>)
    }
}
```